# docker - ubuntu Vs Mac - what is the last version?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, docker

I have a cluster with ubuntu and Mac OS.

On ubuntu my freshly installed docker is v 1.9 :

```
 docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.3
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

On My mac it is 1.12 :

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 23:26:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 23:26:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

What is the correct version ? 
How can I update my Mac's docker ? 
I could'nt really find any information on the web about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.12.3 is the current release and 1.13.0 is nearly ready for release. See https://github.com/docker/docker/releases for the current status.

To upgrade a Ubuntu install, you can run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. If you're not upgrading directly from the docker-project.org repo, see these instructions: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

To upgrade your MacOS version, see the install information on Docker's website: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/